# Creating a Hierarchical Build with SCons

Tags: python, scons

I have a library project that contains some samples in a subfolder.

The library itself has a `SConstruct` file and each sample has its own folder and its own `SConstruct` file.

I'd like to add a target to the main (root) `SConstruct` file which would allow me to compile the library as usual, and all the samples, at once.

Is there an existing mechanism/builder for this ?

P.S: I don't want to have only one big `SConstruct` file because I want the samples folders to remain independant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

> Creating a Hierarchical Build
>
> Notice that the file names specified
>   in a subdirectory's SConscript file
>   are relative to that subdirectory.
>
> SConstruct:
>
> ```
> env = Environment()
> env.Program(target = 'foo', source = 'foo.c')
>
> SConscript('sub/SConscript')
> ```
>
> sub/SConscript:
>
> ```
> env = Environment()
> # Builds sub/foo from sub/foo.c
> env.Program(target = 'foo', source = 'foo.c')
>
> SConscript('dir/SConscript')
> ```
>
> sub/dir/SConscript:
>
> ```
> env = Environment()
> # Builds sub/dir/foo from sub/dir/foo.c
> env.Program(target = 'foo', source = 'foo.c')
> ```

Comment: Couldn't find it in the docs. Exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For those like me coming to this question from Google, I found a more complete example of building a library and code that called it [here](https://github.com/dblalock/scons-example).

(Apologies if this answering of an old question is frowned upon--a large number of searches for various combinations of "scons" "subdirectory" "hierarchical" "build", etc. suggest this page, and I'd like to save others the 8+ hours I just spent trying to get hierarchical builds to work cleanly).

Comment: That's a good reference indeed. After several years, [I could finally achieve my goals](https://github.com/freelan-developers/freelan-all) using SCons hierarchical builds: the project is separated into several libs/samples/apps that all use the same SCons files.