# SCons handle conflicting options in multiple SConstruct files (OptionConflictError)

Tags: scons

I have a project set up with several individual Sconstruct files and one toplevel SConstruct file.

```
project/SConstruct -- toplevel SConstruct file
project/binary1/SConstruct -- lower level SConstructs
project/binary2/SConstruct
project/binary3/src/SConstruct
```

I want to be able to call the individual SConstruct files with options. So each SConstruct can be called like this:

```
scons install --prefix=/usr/local/bin
```

and they have a section for that option in the SConstruct file:

```
AddOption('--prefix',
          dest='prefix',
          type='string',
          nargs=1,
          action='store',
          metavar='DIR',
          default=prefix,
          help='installation prefix')
```

Also, in the toplevel SConstruct file, I would like to be able to call all of the lower level SConstruct files, so I added this to the toplevel SConstruct:

```
SConscript(binary1/SConstruct)
SConscript(binary2/SConstruct)
SConscript(binary3/src/SConstruct)
```

However, if I try to do this, I will get an `OptionConflictError` on `binary2/SConstruct` because the `--prefix` option is already defined (in `binary1/SConstruct`):

```
OptionConflictError: option --prefix: conflicting option string(s): --prefix:
```

Is there a way to get around this `OptionConflictError`?

I know I can surround the call to `AddOption()` with a `try` block, but are there better ways? Can I add a `conflict_handler`? Can I check if the `--prefix` option already exists?

Can I organize things better?  I need the individual SConstruct files unfortunately, so I can't reorganize too much.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to do this by defining SConscript files in the sub-directories: binary1, binary2, and binary3.

I answered a similar question recently and proposed how to organize the SConsctruct and SConscript files, I think that answer would help you:

[Real Hierarchical Builds with SCons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9950474/1158895)

This way you could define the `--prefix` option in the SConstruct files, and from the root SConstruct file, call the subdirectory SConscript files, thus avoiding the afore-mentioned error.

Comment: I am not really having a problem with hierarchical builds, I can get things to build when I remove the `AddOption()` calls.  I think the problem is that `AddOption()` isn't restricted to a specific environment, so each SConscript file is trying to add the same options causing the `OptionConflictError`.  However, the post you linked definitely had some good information. Thank you!

Comment: Ya, I think if you organize your SConstruct and SConscript scripts like the post I referenced, then that should fix your problems. You're right about AddOption(), its a global call, not one that can be called on a specific env. Many SCons funcions can either be called globally, or on a specific env, and it makes sense that AddOption() should be global.